# Vertical Centering of Cell Contents in a Table

Tags: tables, spacing, horizontal-alignment, alignment, vertical

I have used the following table in my document.

```
\begin{table*}[t]
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}A\\B\end{tabular}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}C\\D\end{tabular}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}E \\F\end{tabular}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}G\\H\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{I} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{M} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Q} \\ 
\cline{5-13}
 &  &  &  & J & K & L & N & O & P & R & S & T \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

The result is:
[image]

As you see, all the cells with the content "1111" and the cells containing "J, K, L, N O, P, R, S, T" are not vertically centered. How can I vertically center these cell contents?

Note: I don't want to use `\arraystretch` because it increases the size of the whole table by increasing all the indents. In fact, this is what `\arraystretch` gives, which is not what I want:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you load the `array` package and insert the instruction `\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}` in the preamble.

The following screenshot shows the upper-right corner of the full table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % select a suitable document class
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set margins suitably
\usepackage{multirow,array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*} 
\centering
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt} % what's wrong with the default value (6pt)?
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.5pt} % 1pt is much too wide
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % <-- new
\begin{tabular}{ | *{13}{c|} } 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}A \\B\end{tabular}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}C \\D\end{tabular}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}E \\F\end{tabular}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}G \\H\end{tabular}} & 
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{I} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{M} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Q} \\ 
\cline{5-13}
 &  &  &  & J & K & L & N & O & P & R & S & T \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

---

In a deeper sense, though, the real eason why the problem you've identified is even noticeable is because *you* aren't using the aesthetically best method for constructing the table. What do I mean? I strongly suggest that you eliminate all vertical lines and get rid of almost all `\hline` directives; for the few remaining ones, use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` packages. Similarly, use three `\cmidrule` directives instead of a single `\cline` directive. With far fewer straight lines around, the issue of placing cell contents perfectly centered in a cell simply does't arise to begin with. I.e., something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set margins suitably
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, \cmidrule, and \bottomrule macros

\begin{document}
\begin{table*} 
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ @{} *{13}{c} @{} } 
\toprule
A & C & E & G &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{I} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{M} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Q} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-10} \cmidrule(l){11-13}
B & D & F & H & J & K & L & N & O & P & R & S & T \\ 
\midrule
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\[0.75ex]
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\[0.75ex]
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\[0.75ex]
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\[0.75ex] 
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\[0.75ex]
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\ 
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This one again increases the size of the whole table. I want the height of the whole table to stay unchanged. To address this, I tried decreasing 2pt to 0.85pt in `\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}`. But then the problem again appears: the cell contents would not be vertically centered.

Comment: @Ali - Did you see the addendum I posted? The reason why you apparently feel an urge to fiddle with vertical whitespace adjustments is because you're using a table design approach -- specifically, all those completely unnecessary vertical and horizontal lines -- that's distinctly suboptimal. Get rid of all those lines, and the centering issue never even crops up.

Comment: @Ali - You have to choose from two alternatives: On the one hand, if you insist on drawing lots of visually and aesthetically unnecesssary lines and insist on vertically centering the cell contents, you must either select a positive value for `\extrarowheight` or set `\arraystetch to a value greater than 1. On the other hand, you can choose not to provide all those straight lines, which will let you keep the table nice and compact. Your call.

Answer (score 2):

The best tool for vertical centring of cell contents uses the `cellspace` package: it has commands to define a *minimal* vertical padding at the top and at the bottom of cells in columns with specifier  prefixed with the letter $`S` by default (or any letter you please with the `column=...` key). Here is a code, with some simplifications:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array, multirow, makecell}
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[t]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{|*{13}{Oc|}}
\hline
\multirowcell{2}{A\\B} & \multirowcell{2}{C\\D} & \multirowcell{2}{E \\F} & \multirowcell{2}{G\\H} & \multicolumn{3}{Oc|}{I} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{M} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Q} \\
\cline{5-13}
 & & & & J & K & L & N & O & P & R & S & T \\
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
\hline
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This one also increase the height of the table. The answer works for `\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}` but it increases the tables height. When I change it to `\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{1pt}`, the problem again appears: contents would not be vertically centered.

Comment: Of course, I added what was necessary for vertical padding to be the same  at the top and the bottom of cells.  Other than that, you can use a smaller font size for the table.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to add a bit of spacing. If you load `array` (which you could have done, but I do not know, because you don't include the preamble here) you can change your table definition to:

```
\begin{tabular}{|>{\vrule height1.1em width 0pt\relax}c*{12}{|c}|}
```

and you have some extra upper space in every line (the height is adjusted visually, and notice the use of `*{}{}` to avoid duplicated entries).

[image]

Although I would get rid of vertical and most horizontal lines:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{array, multirow, booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\rowcolors{2}{gray!10}{white}
\begin{tabular}{*{13}{c}}
\toprule
A & C & F & G & \multicolumn{3}{c}{I}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{M}   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Q} \\
\cmidrule{5-13}
\rowcolor{white}B & D & F & H & J & K & L & N & O & P & R & S & T \\
\midrule
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 & 1111 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

If you want to have vertically centered rows, of course you can mix this with  [@Bernard's excellent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/580305/38080)...

[image]

and yes, you have a bit more space, but the table is much more readable now, and you can size it down with a smaller font if needed.